# How to get Text response from DialogFlow agent in android?

Tags: android, chatbot, dialogflow-es

[How do I get this Default response in Android?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P6K8k.png)

I want to get the same response as I get doing this CURL request in android.  Is there a way to do this using API.AI SDK or otherwise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Dialogflow Android SDK](https://github.com/dialogflow/dialogflow-android-client). Check the documentation for integration and accessing the Dialogflow agent.

Get action

```
final Result result = response.getResult();
Log.i(TAG, "Action: " + result.getAction());
```

Get speech

```
final Result result = response.getResult();
final String speech = result.getFulfillment().getSpeech();
Log.i(TAG, "Speech: " + speech);
```

Get metadata

```
final Result result = response.getResult();
final Metadata metadata = result.getMetadata();
if (metadata != null) {
  Log.i(TAG, "Intent id: " + metadata.getIntentId());
  Log.i(TAG, "Intent name: " + metadata.getIntentName());
}
```

Get parameters

```
final Result result = response.getResult();
final HashMap<String, JsonElement> params = result.getParameters();
if (params != null && !params.isEmpty()) {
  Log.i(TAG, "Parameters: ");
  for (final Map.Entry<String, JsonElement> entry : params.entrySet()) {
      Log.i(TAG, String.format("%s: %s", entry.getKey(), entry.getValue().toString()));
  }
}
```

Comment: The SDK is giving me only the intent, not the response string. Can you help me with what part of SDK to use?